# How to do a double loop on json result

Tags: jquery, json, react-native

I have a json result:

[image]

I can do a loop on first level of json, but I cant do a loop on second level (SUBCATEGORIA)

```
<ScrollView>
      {this.state.items.map((item) => (
        <TouchableHighlight
          key={item.id}>

          <View style={{flex:1}}>

            <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row', backgroundColor:item.cor, padding:10}}>

              <View>
                <Text>{item.nome}</Text>
              </View>

            </View>

            <View>
              {this.state.items.subcategoria.map((item) =>{
                <Text>{**HOW DO LIST THE SUBCATEGORIA ITEMS HERE???**}</Text>
              })}
            </View>

          </View>

        </TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<View>
    {item.subcategoria.map(item => <Text>{item}</Text>)}
</View>`

This should give you what you want. You are already mapping over the items of your `state.items` you just need to map over the subcategoria array as well, which is `item.subcategoria` for each of your `this.state.items`

Comment: its works, but if I add extra `{}` like this: `{item.subcategoria.map(item => {<Text>{item}</Text>})}` this not works. why?

Comment: with arrow functions there is something called implicit return
`item => <Text>{item}</Text>` is returning the Text component
`item => { return <Text>{item}</Text>; }` is the equivalent with brackets